# Predicate for fetching children knowing grandchild

Tags: core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I have the following object model in Core Data:

> Factory <-->> Division <-->> Department

Entities with relationships:

> Factory.divisions_ -> Division.departments_

I'd like to fetch **all divisions** for factory knowing ***department*** but struggle to compose the predicate. The best I have not working:

```
let factoryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(divisions_, $division, ANY $division.departments == %@).@count > 0", department)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "factory IN \(factoryPredicate)")
```

What I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Tip: use the inverse relationships: `department.division.factory.divisions_`.

Comment: @Willeke could you please be more specific with some code snippet?

Comment: `let divisions = department.division.factory.divisions_`. I'm not a Swift expert, you might have to add some `?`. Get the division of the department, get the factory of this division and get the divisions of this factory.

Comment: It’s not working this way.

Comment: Can you get the division of the department?